# Как лучше создать систему для ежемесячной оплаты услуг с историей платежей

Tags: php

***Суть:***
Нужно сделать сайт где будет список юзеров с паролями, а также датой окончания оплаты услуги. А так же нужно сделать историю платежей.

***Вопрос:***
Можно ли улучшить мою структуру таблиц для этой задачи?

---

*Я вижу это так:*

- Cоздается таблица `clients`

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| id | name | pass date               | price               |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|    |      | (дата окончания услуги) | (цена, которая      |
|    |      |                         | будет подставляться |
|    |      |                         | в историю оплаты)   |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

- Cоздается таблица `history`, в ячейки которой записываются айди юзеров

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | jan | feb | mar | apr | may | jun | jul | aug | sep | oct | nov | dec |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

В результате вывод истории платежей должен выглядеть так:

```
Юзерник | 15 январь 2015  | 50 рублей  
Юзерник | 13 февраль 2015 | 50 рублей  
Юзерник | 19 март 2015    | 50 рублей
```

и т.д.

Comment: Зачем jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec ?
Замените их на time_payed

Answer (score 1):

Вы сформируйте себе список требований к сайту/проекту, как оно должно работать, потом пройдитесь по плану своей программы.
Первое, что сразу возникает из требований - это секретность и, чтобы история платежей не потерялась. Т.е. как прямой текст пароли нельзя хранить, сохраните только хеши, которые будете проверять и идея про отдельные месяцы-колонки весьма странная - а годы? Почему просто дату платежа не хранить?
Идея вопроса понятна, но сформулирован он не корректно. Сделать можно все разными способами, вам денег платят (или вы собираетесь зарабатывать с проекта) за то чтобы вы взяли на себя ответственность и выбрали решение, а не перекладывали эту ответственность на stackoverflow.
https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html
"Open source - это как свобода выражения, а не бесплатное пиво."

Comment: я не перекладываю ответственность  я спросил как сделать лучше того что я описал вот и все  
если у вас нет ответа на этот вопрос не нужно грузить

..про пароли и все остальное я в курсе

Comment: Соберите требования к проекту, возьмите текущее решение и по пунктам пройдитесь - секретность, производительность, история и др специфичные для проекта. пройдено/пройдено/пройдено ... - все значит ок.

Comment: Вы не правы я задал конкретный вопрос  ---
Я указал свою структуру таблиц и попросил выдать лучший вариант или исправить

Comment: Ваш "конкретный вопрос" не всем понятен, может быть. Мне, например (да и, думаю, многим), очевидно, что при текущей постановке задачи таблица history должна выглядеть как-то так:  `id, user_id, payment_date`. Если очевидный вариант вас по каким-то причинам не устраивает, или есть какие-то дополнительные условия, и т.д., то об этом ничего не сказано, а штатные телепаты  сейчас в отпусках.

Comment: но тогда это будет куча записей в таблице - а с моим вариантов вроед как меньше

Comment: @fosa, базы данных как раз и нужны чтобы хранить кучи записей.